# Have to mimic x-requested-with post call in java

Tags: java, ajax

From my browser I am doing an ajax call to the server so that it sends a response

```
Request URL: https://test.com/ac_helper/
Request Method: POST
**Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded**; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: xxxxxxxxxx
Host: another site
Origin: https://<site>
Referer: https://<site>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
**X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest**
```

Sending body as Form Data:

```
<helperQuery><somefield>something</somefield><password>123</password>    <helperQuery>
```

Response Headers received:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
sei_http_code: 200
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 4670
```

And response received:

```
<helperReply><res>test</res><response>Authentication Success (Y)</response></helperReply>
```

And I have to use java to mimic this browser action of post.

I have tried HttpURLConnection, JSoup, RestAssured.

But none of them worked. Though I managed to get a 200 response using HttpURLConnection, I can't get the response read which is a text/xml response.
Kindly help.

I heard x-requested-with is an inbuilt library browsers use to make ajax calls to the server.